# Which tooltip plugins are compatible with jQuery 1.5 (the current version)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tooltip, qtip

There are a ton of excellent tooltip plugins for jQuery, but most seem outdated. In particular, we wanted to use qTip, but it only supports jQuery 1.3.

Which tooltip plugins support jQuery 1.5?

Which are your favorite tooltip plugins, and why?

Thanks!

Comment: The tooltip plugin. That your going to write, is compliant with jQuery 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think a plugin made to work with jQuery 1.3 won't work in jQuery 1.5?.... from the [qTip site](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/):

> We recommend version 1.3 due to its
>   significant speed increases in several
>   areas, but qTip supports the use of
>   jQuery version 1.2.6 and above for all
>   you who have decided not to upgrade.

Comment: thanks, fudgey. because i read on some forum posts that people were experiencing problems with 1.4 ... i extrapolated, perhaps incorrectly, that the plugin also failed with versions > 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/)

Its easy to use, see the demo, and there is all kind of skins

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of converting from qtip version 1 to qtip version 2 http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

I am using jquery 1.4.4 but according to the documentation it works with jquery 1.5

There are many other features which are included such as ajax, modal etc.

Qtip2 has detailed documentation, various different demos and tutorials.

I went through an entire list here: http://www.enfew.com/21-best-jquery-tooltip-plugins-tutorials/ and decided to settle on qtip1 and as soon as I discovered qtip version 2, I was settled that it provides the best solution for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI Tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip) (still under development) is pretty hardcore - and mostly functional at this point...  There are features that are going to show up before they release it with 1.9, but you could grab the [source from github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.tooltip.js) and take a look at how they implement it.